# Are there any actual implementations that permit `char array[SIZE_MAX];` (or successful equivalent using `malloc`)?

Tags: c, arrays, c99, c11

The C99 standard suggests that the type `size_t` is large enough to store the size of any object, as it is the resulting type of the `sizeof` operator.

> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. ...
>
> The value of the result ... is implementation-defined, and its type (an unsigned integer type) is size_t, defined in  (and other headers).

Since `SIZE_MAX` (`<limits.h>`, if I recall correctly) is defined to be the largest value that a `size_t` can store, it should follow that the largest object would have a size equal to `SIZE_MAX`. That would in fact be *helpful*, but alas it seems as though we'd be asking quite a lot to allocate anything even one quarter that size.

- Are there any implementations where you can actually declare (or otherwise allocate) an object as large as `SIZE_MAX`?

It certainly doesn't seem to be the common case... In C11 the *optional* `rsize_t` type and its corresponding `RSIZE_MAX` macro were introduced. It's supposed to be a runtime constraint if any standard C function is used with a value greater than `RSIZE_MAX` as an `rsize_t` argument. This seems to imply that the largest object might be `RSIZE_MAX` bytes. However, this doesn't seem to be widely supported, either!

- Are there any implementations where `RSIZE_MAX` exists and you can actually declare (or otherwise allocate) an object as large as `RSIZE_MAX`?

Comment: "it should follow that the largest object would have a size equal to SIZE_MAX" - that's not correct.  It merely means that `SIZE_MAX` is at least as large as the largest object can be.

Comment: @MichaelBurr What I meant, when I used the operative keyword *should*, is that `SIZE_MAX` doesn't actually tell us anything useful about objects, but feel free to disregard that part of the question... and please make sure the comments section is left available to ask for clarification, rather than nitpicking on details that don't render the actual question invalid.

Comment: Why, do you expect any answers will tell you anything (practically) useful about the size of the objects? This question is ridiculously theoretic.

Comment: Yes, @KarolyHorvath, I expect that if there are any answers, they'll be naming actual implementations where I can declare or otherwise allocate objects as large as `SIZE_MAX` (and `RSIZE_MAX`)... as that's clearly what my questions are asking.

Comment: I suspect a C-implementation for the 8086 could be much simpler if it limited `SIZE_MAX` to 64k, so any object could *always* fit into a single memory segment.

Comment: @EOF I suspect anything for 8086 could be much simpler if they realized back then that a bunch of 20-bit address registers instead of segments would save decades of segment-pita.

Comment: I'm curious what idea or issue did you encounter before asking this question?

Comment: @user3125367 The issue of growing collections using `realloc`, and determining when an allocation will fail due to sheer size, so as to give up at that point.

Comment: @user3125367: Have you ever worked with 20-bit address registers?  Most languages don't support segmentation very well, but scaled-address segments mean that objects up to 64K can be placed at any 16-byte boundary, while 20-bit address registers complicate working with objects that cross 64K boundaries.  An object-oriented framework like Java, but with 16-bit types, could be very efficient on x86 since references would only have to be 16 bits rather than 32.

Comment: @supercat Be careful not to succumb to tunnel vision when it comes to optimisation; perhaps they didn't perform such an optimisation because it might push other possibilities beyond practicality, or there are more significant issues to consider (e.g. Javas GC). More importantly Java has a 16-bit type; did you consider `short`? There's also `char` which IIRC is a unicode character type, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: @Seb: Java supports packed arrays of `short`, `byte`, and `char`, but it has no other support for anything which is not a multiple of 32 bits.  A variable of type `short` is represented in the Runtime exactly the same way as a variable of type `int`; the only difference from a language perspective is that variables of type `short` can be written into a `short[]` without a cast, and storing a value to a variable of type `short` will sign-extend the lower half into the upper half before it's written.

Comment: @supercat From my OP question you might figure I have expectations that your source of information be credible. Please link me to the section of the JLS that indicates `short` has the same representation. While you're reading the spec, is there any evidence to suggest that `Object` must be internally represented using a multiple of 32 bits?

Comment: @Seb: Instructions exist to load and store from locals values of types `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, and references, and to truncate longer types to shorter ones, and promote `int` or `float` to `long` or `double`, respectively.  Use of `putfield` or `putstatic` requires that a value being stored to a field of type `int`, `boolean`, `byte`, `char`, or `short` must be of type `int`, while those of `long`, `float`, or `double` may only be stored fields of their respective types.

Answer (score 0):

I think all C implementations will allow you to *declare* an object of that size. The OS may refuse to load the executable, as there isn't enough memory.

Likewise, all C runtime libraries will allow you to attempt to allocate that size of memory, however, it will probably fail as there isn't that much memory, neither virtual nor real.

Just think: if `size_t` is a type equal to the machine word size (32 bits, 64 bits), then the highest adressable memory cell (byte) is 2^32 (or 2^64). Given there are lower memory interrupt vectors, BIOS and OS, not to mention the code and data of your program, there is never this amount of memory available.

Comment: Actually, the linker might complain if you declare a huge static or global object.

Comment: The term *implementation* doesn't just apply to the compiler and standard library; it also applies to the runtime environment.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, now I see the issue. Assuming realloc factor of ~1.5, there are two integer limits. First is `SIZE_MAX/3`, because above that `size*3/2` will overflow. But at *that* large low bits are insignificant and we can inverse the operator order to `size/2*3` to still grow by ~1.5 (that imposes second limit of `SIZE_MAX/3*2`). At last, resort to `SIZE_MAX`.

After that, we just have to binary-search the amount that system can actually allocate (in range from the result of growing to minimal required size).

```
int
grow(char **data_p, size_t *size_p, size_t min)
{
    size_t size = *size_p;

    while (size < min)
        size = (size <= SIZE_MAX / 3     ? size * 3 / 2 :
                size <= SIZE_MAX / 3 * 2 ? size / 2 * 3 : SIZE_MAX);

    if (size != *size_p) {
        size_t ext = size - min;
        char *data;

        for (;; ext /= 2)
            if ((data = realloc(*data_p, size + ext)) || ext == 0)
               break;

        if (data == NULL) return -1; // ENOMEM

        *data_p = data;
        *size_p = size + ext;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And none of os-dependent or manual limits!

As you can see, the original question is a consequence of [probably] imperfect implementation that doesn't treat edge cases with respect. It doesn't matter if any questioned systems do or do not exist *now* – any algorithm that is supposed to work near to the integer limits should take proper care of them.

*(Please note that above code assumes char data and has no accounting for other element sizes; implementing that may add more complex checks.)*

Comment: This is all fine and dandy, but I'm not sure how it even attempts to answer the question. It's more an attempt at addressing an irrelevant comment (which you prompted). Please don't do that.

Comment: Your intent seems to to not address the issue right by ensuring there is no succesful implementation that can meet the edge cases (and that leaves the question in widely useless state). I'm leaving this for future comers to not be confused with invalid approaches. For your OP: there are no systems that separate code and data today, so data would be SIZE_MAX, so NO. But please don't settle with anything less than the most portable, standard-compliant solution possible.

Comment: Please don't write answers based on assumptions. My intent is to determine whether there's such an implementation purely out of curiosity, not "to ensure that there is no successful implementation". Can you prove that your code meets all of the edgecases? Perhaps, if by chance there is such a system (e.g. has `SIZE_MAX` defined to some small power-of-two-minus-oneish, e.g. 65535), how will your code allocate the largest possible object? Is there a possibility that your initial loop might have buggy edgecases (think very small values for `size`) causing it to become infinite?

Comment: Though clearly functionality trumps portability and standard compliance in this case (my code is equally portable and standard compliant, yet *actually works correctly*), *how portable is this*? On an implementation that contains *no `realloc`*, this obviously won't work... So you're telling me to choose "the most portable, standard-compliant solution possible"... which obviously isn't your code that has buggy edgecases (possibly wasn't even tested) and won't even compile or run under the most minimal implementations.

Comment: Under that line of reasoning perhaps it would be best to rewrite your answer *without* relying upon `realloc`.

Comment: You correctly noted that initial size of 0 would loop forever. The intent was to show the behavior at the *upper* limit only and not completely proved and tested version, which would be overkill in SO format. With realloc being ISO C, I do not see any problem using it in "standards-compliant" solution though. Now that it is clear that the question was just a curiosity without any accompanying practice I'm flagging this answer as publicly deletable.

Comment: It would also loop forever if the initial size were 1. In any other case, the C standard documents [two forms of environments](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#4p6). `<stdlib.h>` (and by consequence, `realloc`) is required to exist for hosted environments but not freestanding environments... so your example is portable for hosted environments. Mind you, I've recently come to observe some subtle inconsistencies betwixt the standard libraries and implementations of today which would technically place them in the "freestanding with *most* hosted compliance". This question might be one example.

Comment: I decided to publish the function I wrote (the "*imperfect implementation that doesn't treat edge cases with respect*") along with some other [array-operating functions](https://github.com/Sebbyastian/array/blob/master/array.c). Please advise if my "*algorithm that is supposed to work near to the integer limits should take proper care of them*", oh supreme one who can read minds, write awesome buggy code that doesn't work for the lower integer limits and make judgements about pieces of code you've never even seen... P.S. I obfuscated it a little just to upset you ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't review that myself being too busy, buy my qa dep replied "pretty ok except few things" on this. That was a long way, and now your pretty ok. Thank you for remembering this thread!

Comment: It was in writing this code that this question came to mind... Indeed the code (`push_back` especially) is a bit older. You seem to imply that I've learnt a lot over the last year, but I haven't. With regards to C, I've been "learning" it for over ten years now... I think my learning may have stagnated drastically five years or so ago, for some reason... Either I'm running out of things to learn about or I'm a braindead retard who simply can't learn. I expect you already formed your opinion. Does it have any justification?

Comment: *"... there are no systems that separate code and data today, ..."* Are you sure about this? Have you considered any of the microcontrollers that have code on read-only flash and data on DRAM? Perhaps in whatever developing country you're from, you can't afford them (or the textbook/s required to learn about them). Would you like a donation?